How to get the grad of input image of StableDiffusionXLControlNetPipeline
I have another model to generate the input image of StableDiffusionXLControlNetPipeline, and I used the loss based on the output of StableDiffusionXLControlNetPipeline, I want my model can get the grad of the loss.
It seems that the StableDiffusionXLControlNetPipeline's input image can not get the grad.
